# Parsing Multiple Json Rows in windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone

My json response which i am generating from php :

```
{"name":"abhi","age":"20","id":"1"}
{"name":"abhi","age":"21","id":"4"}
```

And the c# code is:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
     // Constructor

    public MainPage()
     {

        InitializeComponent();
     }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Load(textBox1.Text);
    }

    public void Load(string keyword)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/query.php?name="+keyword);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        //request.AddParameter("name", keyword);
        /*request.AddParameter("v", "1.0");
        request.AddParameter("q", keyword);
        request.AddParameter("hl", "id");
        request.AddParameter("rsz", 5);*/
        client.ExecuteAsync<RootObject>(request, (response) =>
        {



               // var resp = response.Data.ToString();
               // var respLines = resp.Split('\n');
                RootObject rootObject=response.Data;
                listBox1.Items.Clear();

                    if (rootObject == null)
                    MessageBox.Show("null");
                    else
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(rootObject.age+" " + rootObject.name);
                    }


        });

    }


}
}
public class RootObject
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string age { get; set; }
  public string id { get; set; }
}
```

i am able to fetch the first row but not for multiple rows. Anyone has any idea how to fetch multiple rows in json format. How to create multiple objects of json and populate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not look like valid JSON, try returning a JSON array from PHP:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {"name":"abhi","age":"20","id":"1"},
    {"name":"abhi","age":"21","id":"4"}
  ]
}
```

These would be the corresponding C# classes for deserialization:

```
public class Row
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
}
```

And you can add your rows with:

```
foreach (var row in rootOject.rows)
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(row.age+" " + row.name);
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to return an array in that format?My current php code is

<?php
  require'connect.php';
header('Content-type: application/json');
 $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"]);

$query="select * from samptable s where s.name='{$name}'; ";

  if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
  {
        
        while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
            
 $jsonresponse=json_encode($query_row);
 print ($jsonresponse);
 echo ",";
        }
      
  }
  else
  {
  echo mysql_error();
  }

?>